# Forwarding all connections to different address

Tags: iptables, nat, linux-networking, forwarding

I have a script that tries to connect to `rabbitmq` using default url and port (`localhost:5672`).

Is it possible to make linux redirect all connections to this url and port to different server?

I am creating some proof of concept and such thing would be useful for me.

Comment: Here is answer http://serverfault.com/questions/247623/iptables-redirect-local-connections-to-remote-system-port

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a better solution for you:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport port -j DNAT --to-destination ip:port
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are asking for a script, so I think you are asking for a userspace tool.

```
nc -l -p 8888 -c "nc example.com 8888"
```